# How to make this C++20 ranges and views implementation work with long long instead of int?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, range, intellisense, c++20

I am experimenting with C++20 Ranges and Views and I've written a fizzbuzz implementation like so:

```cpp
long long std_ranges_views(const long long UPPER_BOUND)
{
    auto range = std::ranges::views::iota(1LL, UPPER_BOUND);
    auto const isMultiple = [](auto n) {return isDivisable(n, { 3,5 }); };
    auto multiples = range | std::ranges::views::filter(isMultiple);
    return std::accumulate(multiples.begin(), multiples.end(), 0LL);
}
```

AFAICT it compiles and runs fine, but in Visual Studio I get some red squiggly lines on the pipe. And: undefined behavior may appear to succeed, so I'm not sure if this code is correct.

[image: Code with Syntax highlighting]

When I hover the mouse over it, it says

> no operator | matches these operands

[image: Tooltip for the squiggly lines]

Usually I'd suspect a type difference like `int` versus `long long`. But I seem to use `long long` everywhere (using the `LL` postfix or `auto`).

When I change all `long long` and `LL` postfixes to `int` instead, the red squiggly lines disappear.

How to make this C++20 ranges and views implementation work with long long instead of int?

Comment: Intellisense is unreliable. Trust the actual compiler.

Comment: Visual Studio and its IntelliSense uses (or at least used) a different parser from its C++ compiler. There have been earlier corner-cases where the two parser didn't agree about code. This could be such a case. If the compiler actually builds it and you get an executable, I'd say there's an IntelliSense problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: okay. Since neither Visual Studio nor [gcc on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jbf6W4czW) have compiler warnings, I'll be confident that everything is fine.